# CryptoDetails is undefined ERROR : cryptoDetails is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vBXN.png)**! This is my CryptoDetails.jsx file **
after rendering this error says cryptoDetails is undefined
what kind of error id this ?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import HTMLReactParser from "html-react-parser";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import millify from "millify";
import { Col, Row, Typography, Select } from "antd";
import {
  MoneyCollectOutlined,
  DollarCircleOutlined,
  FundOutlined,
  ExclamationCircleOutlined,
  StopOutlined,
  TrophyOutlined,
  CheckOutlined,
  NumberOutlined,
  ThunderboltOutlined,
} from "@ant-design/icons";

import {
  useGetCryptoDetailsQuery,
  useGetCryptoHistoryQuery,
} from "../services/cryptoApi";

import LineChart from "./LineChart";

const { Title, Text } = Typography;
const { Option } = Select;

const CryptoDetails = () => {
  const { coinId } = useParams();
  const [timeperiod, setTimeperiod] = useState("7d");
  const { data, isFetching } = useGetCryptoDetailsQuery(coinId);
  const { data: coinHistory } = useGetCryptoHistoryQuery({
    coinId,
    timeperiod,
  });
  const cryptoDetails = data?.data?.coin;

  if (isFetching) return "Loading..";

  const time = ["3h", "24h", "7d", "30d", "1y", "3m", "3y", "5y"];

  const stats = [
    {
      title: "Price to USD",
      value: `$ ${cryptoDetails.price && millify(cryptoDetails.price)}`,
      icon: <DollarCircleOutlined />,
    },
    { title: "Rank", value: cryptoDetails.rank, icon: <NumberOutlined /> },
    {
      title: "24h Volume",
      value: `$ ${cryptoDetails.volume && millify(cryptoDetails.volume)}`,
      icon: <ThunderboltOutlined />,
    },
    {
      title: "Market Cap",
      value: `$ ${cryptoDetails.marketCap && millify(cryptoDetails.marketCap)}`,
      icon: <DollarCircleOutlined />,
    },
    {
      title: "All-time-high(daily avg.)",
      value: `$ ${millify(cryptoDetails.allTimeHigh.price)}`,
      icon: <TrophyOutlined />,
    },
  ];

  const genericStats = [
    {
      title: "Number Of Markets",
      value: cryptoDetails.numberOfMarkets,
      icon: <FundOutlined />,
    },
    {
      title: "Number Of Exchanges",
      value: cryptoDetails.numberOfExchanges,
      icon: <MoneyCollectOutlined />,
    },
    {
      title: "Aprroved Supply",
      value: cryptoDetails.approvedSupply ? (
        <CheckOutlined />
      ) : (
        <StopOutlined />
      ),
      icon: <ExclamationCircleOutlined />,
    },
    {
      title: "Total Supply",
      value: `$ ${millify(cryptoDetails.totalSupply)}`,
      icon: <ExclamationCircleOutlined />,
    },
    {
      title: "Circulating Supply",
      value: `$ ${millify(cryptoDetails.circulatingSupply)}`,
      icon: <ExclamationCircleOutlined />,
    },
  ];

  return (
    <Col className="coin-detail-container">
      <Col className="coin-heading-container">
        <Title level={2} className="coin-name">
          {data?.data?.coin.name} ({data?.data?.coin.slug}) Price
        </Title>
        <p>
          {cryptoDetails.name} live price in US Dollar (USD). View value
          statistics, market cap and supply.
        </p>
      </Col>
      <Select
        defaultValue="7d"
        className="select-timeperiod"
        placeholder="Select Timeperiod"
        onChange={(value) => setTimeperiod(value)}
      >
        {time.map((date) => (
          <Option key={date}>{date}</Option>
        ))}
      </Select>
      <LineChart
        coinHistory={coinHistory}
        currentPrice={millify(cryptoDetails.price)}
        coinName={cryptoDetails.name}
      />
      <Col className="stats-container">
        <Col className="coin-value-statistics">
          <Col className="coin-value-statistics-heading">
            <Title level={3} className="coin-details-heading">
              {cryptoDetails.name} Value Statistics
            </Title>
            <p>
              An overview showing the statistics of {cryptoDetails.name}, such
              as the base and quote currency, the rank, and trading volume.
            </p>
          </Col>
          {stats.map(({ icon, title, value }) => (
            <Col className="coin-stats">
              <Col className="coin-stats-name">
                <Text>{icon}</Text>
                <Text>{title}</Text>
              </Col>
              <Text className="stats">{value}</Text>
            </Col>
          ))}
        </Col>
        <Col className="other-stats-info">
          <Col className="coin-value-statistics-heading">
            <Title level={3} className="coin-details-heading">
              Other Stats Info
            </Title>
            <p>
              An overview showing the statistics of {cryptoDetails.name}, such
              as the base and quote currency, the rank, and trading volume.
            </p>
          </Col>
          {genericStats.map(({ icon, title, value }) => (
            <Col className="coin-stats">
              <Col className="coin-stats-name">
                <Text>{icon}</Text>
                <Text>{title}</Text>
              </Col>
              <Text className="stats">{value}</Text>
            </Col>
          ))}
        </Col>
      </Col>
      <Col className="coin-desc-link">
        <Row className="coin-desc">
          <Title level={3} className="coin-details-heading">
            What is {cryptoDetails.name}?
          </Title>
          {HTMLReactParser(cryptoDetails.description)}
        </Row>
        <Col className="coin-links">
          <Title level={3} className="coin-details-heading">
            {cryptoDetails.name} Links
          </Title>
          {cryptoDetails.links?.map((link) => (
            <Row className="coin-link" key={link.name}>
              <Title level={5} className="link-name">
                {link.type}
              </Title>
              <a href={link.url} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
                {link.name}
              </a>
            </Row>
          ))}
        </Col>
      </Col>
    </Col>
  );
};

export default CryptoDetails;
```

all other things are working well but CryptoDetails is not rendering .
i am not able to understand the problem

Api and all working well but,

Error is **cryptoDetails is undefined **

Comment: You are doing optional chaining on cryptoDetails which means it could be undefined if the optional chain is not defined. You are trying to access the cryptoDetails without checking if its actually defined or not hence you are getting the error.

Comment: what change should i do ?